# How to reconstruct RAID-1 in Ubuntu?

Tags: 13.04, raid

There was RAID-1 device created of two partitions of the similar size on two disks. Disks are not of the same size and there are other (non-RAID) partitions.

During clean install of 13.04, I haven't touched those two partition (left them unformatted and assigned to anything) and now have newly installed system with old (non-RAID) partition regularly accessible. And I have those two partition which were part of RAID-1 device and they are unreadable.

I would like to create RAID-1 using those two partitions. Is it possible to do it, get functional RAID-1 and gain back access to data stored there?

Answer (score 0):

Install the `mdadm` package and the array should show up as /dev/md127 and you should be able to open it in the gui.